# Detect when scrolled to <ul> last <li> inside panel

Tags: jquery, html, css

Cannot catch on scroll in `ul` inside `panel`. I'm trying like this but not work. Can you fix this. thank

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#list').on('scroll', function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

```css
.chat li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
}

.chat li.left .chat-body {
    margin-left: 60px;
}


.chat li.right .chat-body {
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.chat li .chat-body p {
    margin: 0;
}

.panel .slidedown .glyphicon,
.chat .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.chat-panel .panel-body {
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<br />  
<div class="chat-panel panel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="chat" id="list">
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      <li class="left clearfix"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try `$('.panel-body').on('scroll', function() {` Since its your `'.panel-body` that has the height and overflow, and not the #list

Comment: Actually you scrolling "panel-body" not "ul".

Comment: do u want to find last li of ul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.panel-body` is what is scrolling. You can adjust your jQuery to detect that instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.panel-body').scroll(function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

```css
.chat li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
}

.chat li.left .chat-body {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.chat li.right .chat-body {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.chat li .chat-body p {
  margin: 0;
}

.panel .slidedown .glyphicon,
.chat .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.chat-panel .panel-body {
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <br />
  <div class="chat-panel panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="chat" id="list">
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
        <li class="left clearfix"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this below demo:

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8bvea1ba/)**

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.panel-body').on('scroll', function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```